# Convert date into day

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want the below query written in ETL to be converted into Oracle sql. Please help.

```
WITH b1 AS (
SELECT b.fap_inr_idr, b.lod_tmp FROM to_cnf_pye_bse b GROUP BY b.fap_inr_idr, b.lod_tmp
), b2 AS (
SELECT TO_DATE(DATE_SUB(TO_DATE(lod_tmp), DAY(TO_DATE(lod_tmp)) - 1)) AS req_month, b1.* FROM b1
)
SELECT req_month, count(*) AS volume
FROM b2
WHERE req_month < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY req_month
ORDER BY req_month;
```

Comment: Explain the logic for the query.  Also, sample data and desired rsults would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "written in ETL"? ETL is not a language

Comment: It is written in SQL server. I want to subtract days from a date field named lod_tmp which is a timestamp field. But the number of days subtracted is (day of month-1). Eg if I take date as 03/04/1993, then day will be 03 minus 1. And that many days to be deleted from lod_tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Your date calculation formula "date - (day of month - 1)" results in the 1st of the month. So your example date 03/04/1993 would result in the date 03/01/1993 (assuming date format mm/dd/yyyy). The overall query then gets the number of rows in prior months. Thus assuming your column lod_tmp is a string in SqlServer default date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' then your formula:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(DATE_SUB(TO_DATE(lod_tmp), DAY(TO_DATE(lod_tmp)) - 1)) AS req_month
```

translates to Oracle as

```
select trunc( to_date(lod_tmp, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm') req_month.
```

I am not exactly sure what GROUP BY in SqlServer with an aggregate function actually does but in Oracle is eliminates duplicates, I'll assume the same for SqlServer. If so then try:

```
     alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'; 
     with b1 as 
         ( select b.fap_inr_idr, b.lod_tmp  
             from to_cnf_pye_bse b 
             group by b.fap_inr_idr, b.lod_tmp
         ) 
    select trunc(to_date(lod_tmp), 'mm') req_month, count(*) 
      from b1 
     where trunc( to_date(lod_tmp, 'mm') < date '2021-01-01' 
     group by trunc( to_date(lod_tmp, 'mm')
     order by 1;

If you do not want or cannot set nls_data_format then use trunc(to_date(lod_tmp,'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm') ;
```